# Magento 2 : Favicon icon is not showing for Magento root txt files

Tags: magento2.2.3, robots.txt, browser

I have manually created `robots.txt` file and pasted it in the Magento root folder. when I search for `robots.txt` file in the browser, It's not showing favicon icon. I thought I have missed something, but when I look for other text files which are pasted in the Magento root folder, that is also not showing favicon icon.

Could you please clarify and help me to display favicon icon for text files?

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Looking forward to your reply.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

### Adding a custom favicon in Admin

1. Navigate to **CONTENT** >> **Design**  **>> Configuration**.
2. In the scope grid, decide on which level you will configure the favicon and click **Edit** in the corresponding row.
3. Under the **Other Settings** title, expand the **HTML Head** options.
4. Next to **Favicon Icon**, click **Upload**, and select the file.
5. Click **Save Configuration** in the upper right corner to save the changes.

### Add custom favicons manually

> To override the default 16px x 16px favicon manually, add your custom favicon.ico in the /Magento_Theme/web/directory.

1. Add your icons in the <your_theme_dir>/Magento_Theme/web/ directory.
2. In the <your_theme_dir>/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml layout file specify the paths to the icons and their sizes.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <head>
       <link src="Magento_Theme::favicon-32x32.png" rel="icon" sizes="32x32" />
   </head>
</page>
```

For your changes to be applied, clear the browser cache, and the following directories on the server (do not delete the .htaccess file!):

- pub/static
- all directories under var

Answer (score 0):

You can just upload favicon icon from the admin backend and it is default allowed some file types only like `JPG, GIF, PNG, ICO, APNG` and maximun file size is 2MB.

**Admin path :** `Admin -> Content -> Design -> Select your theme (Edit) -> HTML Head -> Upload image on (Favicon Icon) -> Save configuration.`

Then just cache flush and check.